# How to pass/init a struct that will receive a @Published?

Tags: swiftui

I have a class like this:

```
class TextBoxViewParameters: ObservableObject, Codable {
  @Published var text:String
}
```

I have this `text` variable passed to a `TextField` element, like this:

```
struct MyView:View {
  @ObservedObject var textBoxViewParameters:TextBoxViewParameters
  
  init(text:String) {
    self.textBoxViewParameters = TextBoxViewParameters(text: text)
  }
  
  
  var body: some View {
    TextField("New Text", text: $textBoxViewParameters.text)
  }
}
```

Now I want to replace this `TextField` with a `UITextField`.

How do I init that `UITextField` so changes there will be propagated to its parent?

```
 struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

   @ObservedObject var text: String // error here

   init(text: Published<String>) { // I am not sure about this
    self.text = text
   }
 }
```

I have errors everywhere on that init?

Comment: `@ObservedObject` is only for classes that are `ObservableObject`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need binding

```
struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }
```